# Chrome doesn't see custom resolution of CUPS printer

Tags: google-chrome, printing, cups

I just bought a label printer (Zebra ZD420). There a no drivers for this printer, but Zebra says I should install and configure it via CUPS.

I set the default options for the printer in CUPS.
For the media size I selected "Custom" and added the measurements of my paper (105x148mm)
[image: CUPS]
When I print via the mac print interface I see the paper size "custom" and everything prints as I want.

When I try to print via the google chrome print window, it shows me all kind of sizes, but not my custom size.

Is there any way to add this size there? The reason for me to get a label printer is to save time. When I have to click through 3 windows and 2 dropdowns it doesn't save me anything.

[image: Chrome print sizes]

Comment: 105x148 is a standard EU size, A6. Google, as usual, is ignoring the Mac Toolbox & doing its own thing. For some unknown reason it seems to also think you like inches, even though, as a German, you will see even less of them than I do as a Brit ;) CUPS might just have the size as a standard, rather than having to set a Custom. You might get lucky & have Google actually pay attention in that case.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, but unfortunately not. I think the sizes in inches are a result from the printer. Because in the CUPS settings I have a large dropdown with only inches, not a single DIN format. So I had to set it to custom.

Comment: Chrome has a key combo to allow you to print using the system printer interface and not Google’s. I think it’s `Shift-Cmd-P`

Comment: @Allan Yes, it does, but it doesn't work for me (on multiple macs), and even then I can't click brainless on "print" I still have to select the correct preset

Comment: Doesn’t work as in the option isn’t there when using the system print in Chrome?

Comment: @Allan The option is there, the shortcut doesn't work. As I said, I can use the system print options, but then I would have to select the correct preset every single time. One click in chrome for print, click on dropdown for more options, select system print window and finally on print. That are 4 clicks for one label. I want to press CMD + P and Enter, but this won't work because chrome won't show me the correct format.

Comment: Is using command line an option for you?

Comment: @Allan For me, yes, for the others in the office no. If it's a onetime fix I can implement on every mac that's fine. But not if I have to use terminal every time I want to print.

Comment: I was thinking of using `lp` to bypass all these dialogs, but it might not work for other users

Comment: It's amazing how many problems are fixed by not using Chrome. ;-)

Comment: @benwiggy Ok tell me an alternative to chrome that would fix it? Downloading the file and then open it in Acrobat or something isn't a solution, because it also takes multiple steps

Comment: Safari. Vivaldi. Firefox.

Comment: @benwiggy Safari? You can't be serious? Yes, the print might work, but everything else... Firefox doesn't work, has the same problem

Comment: I have a workflow that I use for shipping labels using `lp`.  I’m wondering if it could be adapted to your situation.  It’s bigger than this question has scope for, though